# TYPO3 Add new tab to fe_user

Tags: typo3

I just only begin to develop on TYPO3 version 7.6.16. I use extension femanager. The problem is next:

I want to add my new tab to frontenduser page on backend as it described in this link https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/extension_builder/Developer/ExtendingModels.html

My goal is simple: Add new tab with two fields (Selected Items and Available Items) exactly as it described on the link.

Comment: What does your TCA look like?

Comment: I already fix it! thank you! )

Comment: Documentation about TCA: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/